# Change domain and bring users to the same page as the new domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I changed the tld of my domain from .net to .it.

But I don't want to lose content indexing, and I want to set up a 301 redirect for everyone.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.it [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

This works great but I have a problem: if I'm on the domain.net/rev/1-test page he takes me to domain.it and not in domain **.it**/rev/1-test

how can i make it take me to the new domain but remain on the user's page?

with $1 I don't say to the htaccess to insert everything that is inside to (.*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.net$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.domain.it/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: This actually is not a programming problem. Therefore, you eventually would have been better off posting it on serverfault.com or similar sites.